# Ccылка на поле внешнего класса из вложенного enum

Tags: java

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста. Изучаю Java и возник вопрос. Можно ли получить ссылку из вложенного Enum ссылку на поле внешнего класса? Мне компилятор советует сделать поле статическим, но мне этот вариант не подходит. `{Classname}.this.{field}` тоже не работает.Есть ли ещё какие нибудь способы?

**Update**

---

Хорошо, ссылку я могу передать в созданный enum, а есть ли возможность передать её в момент создания? Я делаю приложение на андроид для интернет магазина, и для всплывающего меню продукта решил использовать enum. Приблизительно так

```
private enum PopupAtion {
    information("Информация о продукте"),
    add_to_favorite(User.favoriteIds().contains(this.product.getProduct_id()) ? "Убрать из избранных" : "Добавить в избранные"),
    add_to_alert(User.alertIds().contains(this.product.getProduct_id()) ? "Убрать из ожидаемых" : "Сообщить о поступлении"),
    add_to_cart("Добавить в корзину");

    String action;

    PopupAtion(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return action;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Enum - это статический объект. Он не может получать доступ к не статическим полям родительского класса напрямую. Как вариант - передавайте в Enum ссылку на объект и пользуйте ее.

Answer (score 2):

Всплывающее меню будет много раз изменяться вслед за требованиями к интерфейсу магазина. Зашивать это в enum - плохо и антипаттерн. При каждом изменении требований вам придется переписывать и перекомпилировать код. При этом совместимость версий будет нарушена. Пользователь с необновленной версией приложения скорее всего не сможет работать с изменившимся API бэкенда.

Рекомендую использовать `List<SomeCustomClass>`, а наполнять его динамически, получая данные от сервера в XML или JSON.